# Storing View ID in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I want to understand how JSF is storing the view and restoring the view. I have read that it is creating the separate view id for each view and storing it on the server. Then it retrieves. The following are my questions:

- In what basis view id is created and stored?
- Is it created based on the JSP's declared on the faces-config.xml?
- Basically is it created for the each JSP one view ID?
- How view ids are passed to render the response? Is it passed in the request parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In what basis view id is created and stored?

The view ID is the context relative path of the view file. E.g. `/foo.jsp` or `/foo.xhtml`. The `ViewHandler` implementation is responsible for creating it and storing it in `UIViewRoot`.

> Is it created based on the JSP's declared on the faces-config.xml?

Those doesn't necessarily need to be declared anywhere in `faces-config.xml`. For every **incoming** request, it's extracted from the request URI by the underlying `HttpServletRequest` object by its [`getPathInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) or [`getServletPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29) methods, depending on whether the `FacesServlet` itself is mapped with prefix pattern (`/faces/*`) or suffix pattern (`*.jsf`) respectively.

When JSF needs to navigate to a **new** view as per a `<navigation-case>` in `faces-config.xml`, then the new view ID is simply extracted from it and a new `UIViewRoot` is created by end of invoke action phase. Otherwise JSF just goes back to the same view as the request was originated.

> Basically is it created for the each JSP one view ID?

Yes, every view has its own unique identifier, which is basically just its location in the webapplication context.

> How view ids are passed to render the response? Is it passed in the request parameter?

They are stored in `UIViewRoot` which is in turn just available by [`FacesContext#getViewRoot()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getViewRoot%28%29). The `ViewHandler` implementation just calls [`getViewId()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewId%28%29) during the [`renderView()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#renderView%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot%29) method.